# $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac {\log(n)}{\log(p_{n})}=1 $ where $p_{n}$ denotes the nth prime

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, limits, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

My professor today in class mentioned that the limit: $$\lim_{n  \to  \infty}\dfrac {\log(n)}{\log(p_{n})}=1$$I'm not sure if I agree since $p_{n}$ grows much faster than $n$. Was his statement correct? And if yes could someone help me understand the intuition behind this.

Comment: Please learn and use *MathJax*.  It isn't that hard, but would be a *great* help to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{p_n}{n \ln n} =1
\implies 
\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln n}{\ln p_n} =\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln n}{\ln (n \ln n)} =  \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln n}{\ln n +\ln \ln n} = 1 
$$